# Blazor Select/Option not binding

Tags: html, razor, blazor

attempting to get a select/option html element to work in my blazor app, but the binding of the string continues to be "empty"

What am I not understanding?

```html
/* It even defaults to so "A B C" but still is not bound */
<select bind="@divValue">
    <option value="ABC">A B C</option>
    <option value="DEF">D E F</option>
    <option value="GHI">G H I</option>
</select>


@code {

    string divValue = string.Empty;

    ....

   /* value = string.Empty still*/
   string test = divValue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data binding syntax

```
@page "/"

    <div class="row ">
        <select @bind="divValue" class="col-sm-2 form-control">

                <option value="ABC">A B C</option>
                <option value="DEF">D E F</option>
                <option value="GHI">G H I</option>
            </select>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <input @bind="divValue" class="col-sm-2 mt-3 form-control"/>
    </div>


    @code {

        public string divValue;

    }
```

Comment: Yes the key is @bind="divValue"

Comment: This did it. Thanks so much guys :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<select @bind="divValue">
    <option value="ABC">A B C</option>
    <option value="DEF">D E F</option>
    <option value="GHI">G H I</option>
</select>

@divValue

@code {

    string divValue;

}
```

Comment: exception thrown - divValue can't be null.

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: @maddyhatty23 Sorry I should have been clearer about where the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Use InputSelect instead of Select and bind value with its @bind-value attribute.

You can find the example [here](https://justdebug.net/blazor/top-20-blazor-questions-and-answers/#how-to-create=custom-inputselect-element-in-blazor).

Thanks